Did Jehovah transform the firstborns of Egypt into cats?
Many of the plagues God sent upon the Egyptians involved crazy miracles like turning the Nile into blood or turning sand into gnats. Are there any interpretations that say that the final curse (death of the firstborn) involved the firstborn sons of Egypt being transformed into cats?
Is it possible to interpret the Hebrew verb "to slay" as "to turn into an animal"?
It's not inconsistent with the rest of the plagues of Egypt, and the Egyptians were known for worshipping cats after all...

The middle question should be asked on BH-SE.  Then, perhaps, the question here will be put to rest.

A talking donkey (Numbers 22:28-31) or snake (Genesis 3:1-5) may also seem "crazy". At least until people take into consideration that there are such things as spirit beings who are invisible to us humans, and can make it appear like a voice is coming from something that normally does not speak. Turning dust to gnats was not any different from what God was described as doing during the creation days, in Genesis 2:7, 19. And turning water to blood is similar to what Jesus did when he turned water to wine in John 2:3-10.

This article discusses the purpose of all the plagues God brought upon Egypt.  Here follows a brief summary:

The first plague, turning the Nile to blood, was a judgment against Apis, the god of the Nile, Isis, goddess of the Nile, and Khnum, guardian of the Nile.


The second plague, bringing frogs from the Nile, was a judgment against Heqet, the frog-headed goddess of birth. Frogs were thought to be sacred and not to be killed.


The third plague, gnats, was a judgment on Set, the god of the desert.


The fourth plague, flies, was a judgment on Uatchit, the fly god.


The fifth plague, the death of livestock, was a judgment on the goddess Hathor and the god Apis, who were both depicted as cattle.


The sixth plague, boils, was a judgment against several gods over health and disease (Sekhmet, Sunu, and Isis).


The ninth plague, darkness, was aimed at the sun god, Re, who was symbolized by Pharaoh himself.


The tenth and last plague, the death of the firstborn males, was a judgment on Isis, the protector of children.

The answer to your question is NO, the God of Israel did not transform the firstborns of Egypt into cats.  Furthermore, the plagues were not “crazy”.  They sent a powerful message to the Pharaoh and his subjects.  The plagues were specifically directed against the false gods and goddesses of Egypt.  They were sent to teach them an important lesson – their gods and goddesses were impotent.
After God, the Judge of all the earth, drowned all of Pharaoh’s armies, the power of Egypt was crushed, and the fear of God spread through the surrounding nations (Joshua 2:9–11). This was the very purpose that God had declared at the beginning.
